# SVG cover strip modeling software

Tags: math, svg, geometry

I am in a refactoring process for a client where their 2D modeling software needs to be rewritten. There is poor old logic for scaling things down that does not fit in the canvas. I was wondering can anyone provide a proper mathematical formula to scale down a vector based on canvas size, most important thing is that the ratio should be kept between lines when scaling down.

**One single formula is not required I can take any suggestions with using any programming language.**

Example image:

[image]

Incase someone models a 2000mm width cover strip the drawn line should be downscaled to fit in the canvas. In this case, pixels and millimeters are proportional.

I have tried using exponential downscaling like this, but that does not count the canvas size in any way.

- `20mm^0.85=12.76mm`
- `10mm^0.85=7.07mm`
- `5mm^0.85=3.92mm`

I know this is more a mathematical question, but it's more like a programming problem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not specifying any language, I will outline the procedure. It is very easy to implement, for instance, in `javascript`. Let `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` the width and height of the canvas, and `object.width` and `object.height` the width and height of the object.

- Start by calculating `scx = object.width / canvas.width` and `scy = object.height / canvas.height`.
- If you only want to downscale (never upscale), then: If both `scx` and `scy` are lower than 1, then do nothing (the object fits). In any other case, the largest value `max(scx, scy)` is your scale factor. You must divide `object.width` and `object.height` by that scale factor.
  *If you always want to fit the object to the canvas, then the largest value `max(scx, scy)` is your scale factor. You must divide `object.width` and `object.height` by that scale factor.

Just one more advice: you can easily set a margin (actually padding) by using a lower `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`. Say you use 90% of the actual sizes. Then you can set the origin point at 5% of the width and the height and you know that no object will be closer than 5% to any canvas limit.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, clearly explained as well. Cheers!